# I am creating a chat, but everytime I send a message, it will not let me send another message, like the form won't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chat

When I post a message into my chat, it won't let me post again. I believe this is the code associated with the sending:

```
window.typing = false;
var posted = 0;
var canPost = 1;
var donotrefresh = 0;

document.forms['send'].addEventListener('submit', function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    if (!this.message.value || !canPost) {
        return 0;
    }
    var form = this;
    var message = this.message.value;
    this.message.value = "";
    this.message.focus();
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    posted = 1;
    canPost = 0;
    chat.refresh();
    chat.messages.scrollTop = 0;

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.readyState >= 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            if (!ajax.responseText) {
               canPost = 1;
               posted = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    ajax.open("GET", "/chat/ajax.php?req=post&chatmsg=" + encodeURIComponent(message), true);
    ajax.send(null);
}, false);
```

And here is my submit code:

```
<form name="send" style="height:100px;width:100%">
    <input type="text" name="message" style="width:60%;height:2em;resize:vertical;opacity:0.8;" maxlength="220" placeholder="Your message to send..." required />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" style="vertical-align:top;opacity:0.8;" />
</form>
```

Comment: why this `canPost = 0 ` ?

Comment: What have you tried? What exact behavior do you see when you "can't post again"? What have you looked for in the browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: Are you sure the ajax request gets completed successfully? If not canPost would never be set to 1 again and therefore your early return would cancel further approaches to send a message. Either look at the "network" tab of your javascript console or insert a breakpoint (or a simple logging output) to the callback function (the one where you set canPost = 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove if (!ajax.responseText)

```
ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (ajax.readyState >= 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
        canPost = 1;
        posted = 0;
    }
}
```

Do you need the "posted" variable?  Looks like this isn't used by the code anymore.  The purpose of canPost seems to me to avoid to requests at the same time.  Is it really a point to avoid that here?

Comment: Thanks so much @jan this worked perfectly! I don't really know what your question asked but it does what I need so I am glad, thank you :)